# How to tally occurrences of an object key without using for loop JS

Tags: javascript, object, filter, count, key

I have been given this function and I would like to know how to count the number of people who live in a city without using a for loop

```
function tallyPeopleInManchester(people) {


/* This function receives an array of people objects in for format:
[
  { name: 'Emmeline', lives: { country: 'UK', city: 'Manchester' }, age: 32 }
]

The function should return the number of people who live in the city of Manchester
*/
```

Comment: Filter the array then take its length

Comment: please can you give me a nudge in the right direction I have tried the following but am getting an error...people.filter(i => (i.lives && i.lives.city === 'Manchester')).length // my error is AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

newtojs,

Maybe this could help you:

```
return people.filter(p => p.lives.city == 'Manchester').length
```

Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: thanks Ric, for some reason I got an error // AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 2
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +2

Comment: mocha? you must re-evaluate your tests.